# Mongo map/reduce slowdown on large collections

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

We have a seemingly simple map/reduce job that goes through logging data on a daily basis. On the development server, we can run this job over a very large number of documents, ~1M, and it takes about a minute with no problems. We move the job over to the production servers, which are Amazon EC2 servers, the job will crank through about 50% of the rows at a very fast rate, then crawl through the rest of the data. It can take hours to go through several hundred thousand documents, instead of the expected minute or two. So I am hoping we have made an obvious mistake in the map/reduce job.

Here is a sample input document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f147a92d72b292c02000057"),
    "cid" : 25,
    "ip" : "123.45.67.89",
    "b" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7",
    "r" : "",
    "l" : "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "ts" : ISODate("2012-01-16T19:29:22Z"),
    "s" : 0,
    "cv" : "4f143a5fd72b292d7f000007",
    "c" : ""
}
```

We query for a range of _id's only.

Here is the map code:

```
function() { 
    var browser = {}
    ,referrer = {};
    browser[this.b] = {
        'count': 1
    };
    referrer[this.r] = {
        'count': 1
    };
    var objEmit =  {
        'count': 1
        ,'browsers' : browser
        ,'referrers' : referrer
    };
    var date = this._id.getTimestamp();
    date.setHours(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    emit({'cv' : this.cv, 'date' : date, 'cid' : this.cid }, objEmit);
};
```

Here is the reduce code:

```
function (key, emits) {
    var total = 0
    ,browsers = {}
    ,referrers = {};
    for (var i in emits) {
        total += emits[i].count;
        for (var key in emits[i].browsers) {
            if (emits[i].browsers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                !(browsers[key]) && (browsers[key] = { count : 0 });
                browsers[key].count +=  emits[i].browsers[key].count;
            }
        }
        for (var key in emits[i].referrers) {
            if (emits[i].referrers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                !(referrers[key]) && (referrers[key] = { count : 0 });
                referrers[key].count += emits[i].referrers[key].count;
            }
        }
    }
    return {'count' : total, 'browsers' : browsers, 'referrers' : referrers}
};
```

No finalize, and we output the map/reduce job to an existing collection with the "merge" option set to true.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the same code running in dev and production, and you've run it in dev on very-large sets and it's returned very quickly, any particular reason why you suspect your code may be at fault?

Is it possible that you're running on a Micro instance? In case you didn't know, [Micro instances cap average CPU usage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html) and that may be damaging your Map-Reduce activity by causing a huge queue of data to build up without being allowed to process it (I/O isn't being capped in the same way, so that keeps coming in and the Linux kernel then spends most of its time managing that and making things even worse).

Switching from Micro to Small, even with the lower CPU speed, may help you out because you have a constant "flow" of CPU cycles to work with (as normal machines always have) and MongoDB's internal scheduling will probably better adapt.

This may not have been an issue before because the normal query "spikes" don't last long enough to cause the CPU limit to turn on.

Comment: Thanks. CPU usage does seem to get pinned on production, so this might be on the right track. We are supposedly not using a micro instance, but a "high-memory double extra large."

Comment: What sort of specs does your dev machine have? That kind of instance shouldn't be having these problems. I'd also look into the setup of MongoDB on dev versus production. Are they the same version, same settings, same architecture (dev and production both 64-bit)?